# Htaccess allow access to directory only for mobile device

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to allow access to a character directory and his subdirectory too, only for mobile device.

I write this condition but that not work , this is my htaccess rules:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
##Setting rewrite base to / here.
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on

**RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(iphone|ipad|android) [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} character [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]**

##Rewriting for page1 uri here.
RewriteRule ^page1$ page1.php    
##External redirect rules here.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/FOF/news/page/page1\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /customPage? [R=301,L]

##Internal rewrite rules here...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^customPage/?$ FOF/news/page/page1.php [L,NC]
```

Thank for help

Answer (score 0):

Just block url request from any other device other than mobile to character folder/directory then it should only allow requests from mentioned devices to that folder.

Make sure to place these rules at the top of your htaccess rules file.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(iphone|ipad|android) [NC]
RewriteRule ^character - [F,L]
```

***2nd solution:*** Above solution considers that your `character` directory stays in root directory if it can be any sub-directory in whole uri itself then try following.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(iphone|ipad|android) [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} character [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Comment: Thank to your answer, when I try your updated rules that not work, the content of character directory and his subdirectory contents are still accessible if I don't use a mobile

Comment: @user1887842, is `character` folder is under root folder? Can your urls be like `http://localhost:80/test/character/test123/` also? Please confirm once.

Comment: The character folder is here http ://mywebsite/FOF/character/test123/

Comment: @user1887842, then please try my just now updated 2nd solution once and let me know how it goes?

Comment: Still same, url was accessible since other no mobile device

Comment: @user1887842, ok could you please make sure one thing that condition `!(iphone|ipad|android)` has all devices names in it which you want to ACCESS so that it works for only devices which you want. Basically what it does is: if request's agent is NOT in this list(`!(iphone|ipad|android)`) and its accessing character then block it. Let me know on same, cheers.

Comment: Yes I think I try the url in Iphone 11 mobile device, I made an error when I write this rules ```RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} character [NC]``` I write the rule like ```RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !character [NC]``` but now with ```RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} character [NC]``` rules the directory are not accessible with de mobile too

Comment: @user1887842, I am not sure on HTTP_USER_AGENT value for iphone-11. You should use `RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(iphone|ipad|android) [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} character [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]` rules like I posted in my 2nd solution, looks like you are using my previous code, please try exact same code in my 2nd solution and let me now how it goes then?

Comment: To be sure this line in my case need to be like this : ```RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} FOF/character [NC]``` ?? because my character folder is inside the FOF folder too. If this line is good, my rules are exactly the same as your 2nd solution

Comment: @user1887842, no that will match anywhere character so it should be fine, please try it out once 2nd solution.

Comment: Changing this ```RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} FOF/character [NC]``` TO ```RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} character [NC]``` ,character directory are not accessible since mobile too

Comment: @user1887842, ok so its blocking both device other than mobile AND mobile both? Do you have any other rules related to this apart from these?

Comment: I update my question with all my htaccess rules

Comment: @user1887842, ok, is your htaccess present inside root? or inside FOF folder? Please confirm once.

Comment: Is inside root.

Comment: @user1887842, ok, could you please do change your `RewriteBase` line to `RewriteBase /FOF/` once and try again? Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. Let me know how it goes then.

Comment: Now when I change RewriteBase by RewriteBase /FOF/, the directory are accessible from both, and the rewriting rules are not working too

Comment: @user1887842, what error its giving? is it giving forbidding error?

Comment: I change my previous answer, rewriting rules are working, but directory are not accessible from both

Comment: @user1887842, may be it was cache problem? If it was a cache problem then change back to `RewriteBase /` once? Let me know how it goes.

Comment: No any change when I put RewriteBase/  directory are not accessible from both

Comment: @user1887842, please do let me know which sample url and folders are not working? Considering that your main issue of accessing character folder is accessible from mobile only is FIXED now.

Comment: This one, is not accessible from mobile and not mobile device too : http://localhost:80/FOF/character/test123/

Comment: @user1887842, ok looks like you don't have real page/directory named test123? If yes then do you want this page to be served with index.php? Kindly confirm once.

Comment: No test123 not exist , the real url are http://localhost:80/test/character/spiderman/ and http://localhost:80/test/character/batman/ , and inside this directory no index.php file but only images, I just want this url can't be accessible from all external device except iphone ipad and android phone

Comment: @user1887842, ok then from which file these non-existing pages should be served from? Or in simple words what contents(from which file) it should for all thee kind of changes?

Comment: actually the content of http ://localhost:80/test/character/spiderman are directly accessible from the url of the image with a IOS function like ```NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http ://localhost:80/test/character/spiderman/img1.jpg"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];``` , so the http ://localhost:80/test/character/spiderman/img1.jpg need to be blocked if someone put the url of the image in a browser, only the mobile need to access to this files in this character folder

Comment: @user1887842, ok so right now, your images are not accessible but your requests are only accessed by mobile correct? I am not sure which rules are these which you posted in previous comments. How about rewritebase is it working with `/`? Please clarify on these once, so that we can further investigate it.

Comment: If I keep the rules like that ```Rewritebase / RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(iphone|ipad|android) [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} character [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]``` the images in folder character are accessible from both and if I change Rewritebase / to Rewritebase /FOF/ that have no effect